# Chrome/Firefox hitting page twice

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I log every time our Coldfusion site is accessed.
In Chrome/Firefox (latest both) when I hit the site it by either copy/pasting the URL or clicking a link the site get hit twice. This does not happen on IE or Edge.
These double hits are causing a problem.

Comment: obtain more data. what request headers? what urls? enable verbose server logs or the browser's http request dev tools

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had a css line that was "background-image:url();"